# Docker-compose build misses some package content in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm working on build containers exploiting a monitoring application (Centreon).
When i build my container manually (with docker run) and when i build my docker file, i have different results. Somes scripts used by the application are missing.

Here's my dockerfile :

```
FROM centos:centos7
LABEL Author = "AurelienH."
LABEL Description = "DOCKERFILE : Creates a Docker Container for a Centreon poller"

#Update and install requirements
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y wget nano httpd git

#Install Centreon repo
RUN yum install -y --nogpgcheck  http://yum.centreon.com/standard/3.4/el7/stable/noarch/RPMS/centreon-release-3.4-4.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

#Install Centreon
RUN yum install -y centreon-base-config-centreon-engine centreon centreon-pp-manager centreon-clapi
RUN yum install -y centreon-widget*
RUN yum clean all

#PHP Time Zone
RUN echo -n "date.timezone = Europe/Paris" > /etc/php.d/php-timezone.ini

#Supervisor
RUN yum install -y python-setuptools
RUN easy_install supervisor
COPY /cfg/supervisord.conf /etc/

RUN yum clean all

EXPOSE 22 80 5667 5669

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "--configuration=/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

The difference i see is in the */usr/lib/nagios/plugins folder*. I miss some scripts here. And when i execute the exact same commands but in a container i'm running i can find my files.
Maybe it has something to do with writing permissions for the user that executes the commands with docker-compose ?

EDIT :
docker-compose file :

```
version: "3"

services:
  centreon:
    build: ./centreon
    depends_on:
    - mariadb
    container_name: sinelis-central
    volumes:
      - ./central-broker-config:/etc/centreon-broker
      - ./central-centreon-plugins:/usr/lib/centreon/plugins
      - ./central-engine-config:/etc/centreon-engine
      - ./central-logs-broker:/var/log/centreon-broker
      - ./central-logs-engine:/var/log/centreon-engine
      - ./central-nagios-plugins:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins
      - ./central-ssh-key:/home/centreon/.ssh/

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "5667:5667"
      - "5669:5669"
      - "22:22"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        window: 300s
    links:
    - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: sinelis-mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passwd2017
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        window: 300s
```

To run the container I use the *docker run -it centos:centos7* command

Comment: How do you run your container? Update your question to include cli flags, docker-compose.yml file, and in particular any volume definitions.

Comment: What are cli flags ?

Comment: Edited to add docker-compose file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you put in your image at that location, you will always see the contents of your volume mount:

```
  - ./central-nagios-plugins:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins
```

Docker does not initialize host volumes to the contents of the image, and once you have data in the volume, docker does an initialization with any volume type.

Keep in mind the build happens on an image without any of the other configurations in the compose file applied, no volumes are mounted for you to update. Then when you run your container, you overlay the directories of the image with the volumes you select. Build time and run time are two separate phases.

---

Edit: to have a named volume point to a host directory, you can defined a bind mount volume. This will not create the directory if it does not already exist (the attempt to mount the volume will fail and the container would not start). But if the directory is empty, it will be initialized to the contents of your image:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  central-nagios-plugins:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins

services:
  centreon:
    ....
    volumes:
      ...
      - central-nagios-plugins:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins
      ...
```

It will be up to you to empty the contents of this volume when you want it to be reinitialized with the contents of your image, and merging multiple versions of this directory would also be a process you'd need to create yourself.

Comment: Well does it count if the volume is initialized ? Or doesn't exist yet ?
I want my container to initialize this folder with the content from the build and i want to be able to save it between restarts of the container.
The reason is that this folder should contain the standard scripts and some custom on top of it.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you already have saved data in the volume and have an updated image from a new build?

Comment: Ideally, i would like to save my volumes in a separate folder on the host machine (for history purposes), then build and launch the new image.
Once the Image is launched nad my unit tests are done, i would like to reintegrate my specific content in my volumes.

Comment: @Aurelien I've provided the key step, changing the host volume to a named volume to get docker to initialize it from the image when it's empty. The process to save each version to a different directory and perform some kind of merge would need to be a process you create.